# Difficulty Understanding ODE Integral Curve Problem Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

I completed the following ODE problem:

**Problem**

> One of the integral curves seems to be a straight line. Is this true? What straight line is it? (i.e., for what m and b is y = mx + b a solution?)

However, I'm having difficulty understanding part of the following (given) solution:

**Given Solution**

> Yes, one of the curves seems to be a straight line. You can guess visually from the applet that the linear solution seems to be the graph of the function $y = \dfrac{1}{2}x − \dfrac{1}{4}$ . You can verify this guess is indeed a solution to the equation by checking that $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{2} = x − 2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{1}{4}\right) = x − 2y.$
>
> This answer can also be computed without guesswork. If $y = mx + b$ is a solution, then
>
> $m = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = x - 2y = x - 2(mx + b)$
>
> or, rearranging terms,
>
> $m = (1 − 2m)x − 2b$.
>
> Two polynomials in $x$ can only the same for all $x$ (over the reals) if they have the same coefficients. Equate coefficients of the powers of $x$ to get two equations in two unknowns that must be satisfied simultaneously.
>
> $m = -2b$ and $0 = 1 - 2m$
>
> From the second equation, $m = \dfrac{1}{2}$. Plugging this into the first equation gives $b = − \dfrac{1}{4}$.

All grammatical errors are part of the solution and, therefore, not mine.

I don't understand how we get $m = -2b$ and $0 = 1 - 2m$? My initial thoughts were that we would need the coefficients to be the same, which would mean that we require $1 - 2m = 1$? Although, I'm not sure where the $m = -2b$ comes from.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this solution.

Comment: It is not easy to talk about the solutions of an ODE... without actually seeing the ODE :)

Comment: @MiguelAtencia $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x - 2y$. It is discernible from reading the solution.

Comment: IMHO the question should include the equation, to avoid putting the burden on the reader of discerning the statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. By  letting $y=mx+q$ we find that the ODE is satisfied for all real $x$ iff
$$y'+2y-x=m+2(mx+q)-x=(2m-1)x+(m+2q)=0$$
which implies that the coefficients of the polynomial in $x$ are all zero, that is $m=1/2$ and $q=-1/4$. Hence $y(x)=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}$ is the ONLY linear solution.

Note that the general solution of the ODE is
$$y(x)=Ce^{-2x}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{4}.$$ 
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.